# Stripe Checkout & webhooks clarification for a subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm setting up Stripe checkout for my MEVN web app, and I'd like a bit of clarification. I'm finding the docs quite confusing, there seems to be lots of different options and it's hard to know what to follow.

I'd like to know, would this work for my subscription web app use case?

1. Set up Stripe Checkout and add the no-code link to my web app with the redirect success and cancel links
2. Set up webhooks to amend user data on my backend when a user subscribes (but how do I know which user it is?

Sorry if these are basic questions. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days and it's best if I understand this at the most basic level. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout) is not *entirely* "no code". You still need to create a Checkout session on your server.  However it does take care of all the heavy lifting around secure payment collection and handling local payment methods.

If you are authenticating your users in your application you can use the subscription [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-metadata) to append some `key:value` pairs to help you identify which of your users the webhook notification corresponds to.

You can also consider making use of the [Customer Stripe model](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer) to help keep track of which of your users are subscribed to what products/services directly in Stripe.  However I would advise you to also track your users in the DB for your app (and likely store the Stripe Customer ID field in your User model).

The first link I provided is a walk-through for using Stripe Checkout with Subscriptions and I would recommend starting there.